# MS Graph cycling through each item in IListItemsCollectionPage

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I have a piece of code, which pulls items from a SPO List. How should I write the foreach / select type to be able to read item.Title f.e?

Tried to type the var item to multiple types and could not get the right outcome...

```
var items = await graphServiceClient.Sites["yourtenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/ITOddeleni:"].Lists["TeamsRequest"].Items
     .Request(queryOptions)
     .GetAsync();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I would expect it to write out a string with the Title of the Item.
All I get out of it now is 2x Microsoft.Graph.ListItem (as I have 2 items in the list)

Comment: what you read is the output of the `ToString()` method which gets inherited by every object in C# from the class `object`. If not overriden it will print by default the entire class name (as it is in your case). You would need to print it by hand, all the values that you expect to read

Comment: making it Console.WriteLine(item.ToString()); does not change a thing, did I get you wrong?

Comment: yes you did, you would need to write `Console.WriteLine($"Title: {item.Title}")` or something like this. I don't know what data type item is....

Comment: Microsoft.Graph.ListItem it is... Managed to get the ID of it by Console.WriteLine($"Title: {item.Id}") but it does not suggest Title at all :-(

Comment: how about `name`? have a look on the [properties in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Tried name right away as I saw it, but does not come back with title... and Name and Title in SP is a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
                {
                    new QueryOption("expand", "fields(select=id,Title)")
                };



                var items = await graphServiceClient.Sites["yourtenant.sharepoint.com"].Lists["TeamsRequest"].Items
                     .Request(queryOptions)
                     .GetAsync();




                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Fields.AdditionalData["Title"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Name:" + item.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {item.Id}");
                }
```

The item.Fields.AdditionalData does the thing. Thanks for your suggestions :-)